# Calculating time difference (PHP)

Tags: php, function, time, strtotime

Here's my function

```
<?php    
//Find time difference
    function timeDifference($timeEnd, $timeStart){
      $tResult = strtotime($timeEnd) - strtotime($timeStart);
      return date("G:i", $tResult-3600);
    }
?>
```

And an example

```
<?php
   echo timeDifference(12:00:00,08:30:00);
?>
```

The results on my localhost was fine but online on my server it's showing 21:30 when it's supposed to be 3:30. What could do that?

**UPDATE**

Here my solution for php 5.2

```
<?php
//Find time difference
function timeDifference($timeEnd, $timeStart){
  $tResult = round(abs(strtotime($timeEnd) - strtotime($timeStart)));
  return gmdate("G:i", $tResult);
}
?>
```

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.3, it comes with a built-in [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function.

It might be easier than trying to debug your own function.

By the way, the code you've given:

```
echo timeDifference(12:00:00,08:30:00);
```

is never going to work, because you haven't got quotes aruond the time strings. I assume that's a typo in the question, since you claim that the function is returning results (even if they're incorrect)

Comment: I have 5.2.17 :( Can't use it

Comment: @Warface - you really ought to upgrade; 5.2 is no longer supported. (I appreciate this isn't always an option, but if possible, you should do so)

Comment: I'll accept this answer for those who are on 5.3, if not my update in my question could be an alternative. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This could be a timezone issue. Try setting the timezone with this function at the top of your PHP page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: No with <?
echo date("G:i:s");
?> it show the right time on my server.

Comment: Then you may want to try the 24hr format option mentioned as a comment in the OP, or the date_diff() function mentioned by Spudley.